# MVC Solution builds locally but not on TeamCity

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, teamcity

Please can somebody help.

I have a solution that build locally and on another machine when checked out from Subversion however when I try to build it using the MSBuild tool on my TeamCity server I get some form of assembly referencing problem

*[08:33:32][Csc] Controllers\AccountsController.cs(422, 26): error CS1061: 'PF.ENTITIES.PF022.Item' does not contain a definition for 'OperationStatus' and no extension method 'OperationStatus' accepting a first argument of type 'PF.ENTITIES.PF022.Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

The PF.ENTITIES.PF022 assembly does have the correct property for OperationStatus and as I said it runs fine locally.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if this dll is set as "Copy locally"?

**To set the Copy Local property to True or False**

In Solution Explorer, click the Show All Files button to display the References node.

Open the References node for the project.

Right-click a reference in the References list, and click Properties.

The properties associated with that reference appear in a list in the Properties window.

Select Copy Local from the left-hand column, and then click the arrow in the right-hand column to change the value to True or False.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thiago but unfortunately that isnt it.  I have that set for every referenced assembly.  When I run it locally it uses a version of my assembly with the changes, however when it runs from TeamCity it seems to create an older version.  I have removed everything from SubVersion to make sure it builds from scratch.  There are cross dependencies in my project though so could another project be created/overwriting a newer version (every project has this assembly referenced via the project though not the DLL)

Comment: Have you already checked the IIS/Application Pool setup? Maybe the reference is set to the wrong version of your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Project Dependencies.

I wanted to build the whole Solution in TeamCity but I would now advise against this.  Rather build individual projects always within the solution,  that way you can arrange your build order and set some dependencies (do the same for your CI Deployment System too)

That way you can ensure certainly libraries are in place before you build other projects.